# In Python, how to automatically import all nested packages without namespace override?

Tags: python, python-import

I have a 2-layer package:

```
package1
|--package2
|  |--function1
|  |--function2
|--package3
```

I'm trying to avoid name/import conflict as much as possible, so I import all members in a package without changing there namespaces, then use the functions by their full name:

```
import package1 as package1

package1.package2.function1(...)
```

However, the interpreter gave me the following error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'package2'
```

This seems to be illogical since package2 is definitely in the namespace of package1, which I have already imported. If I would like to keep using my function call format, what kind of import should I use WITHOUT referring to package2 and package3?

I've also tried the following:

```
import package1.*               (doesn't work)
from package1 import * as package1.* (obviously doesn't work)
from package1 import *          (works but bad practice, causes naming conflict)
```

But non of them fulfils my need.

Comment: Where did you import `package2`? Sub-packages are *not* automatically available as attributes without importing.

Comment: I didn't import it but refer to it in my function call, is there a way to import subpackages without overriding namespace?

Comment: Ah, re-reading that sentence I see you didn't claim you imported it. No, importing *just* `package1` does not import all subpackages (that'd be rather resource intensive and would make it impossible to load a package lazily).

Comment: You'd import the nested names in the `package1/__init__.py` file to make them available immediately.

Comment: That works for some cases but in my case it causes cyclic import error, package2 uses lots of things in package1, so package1 can no longer import package2 :-<

Comment: Then either avoid those circular imports (move those to a separate module perhaps?) or require that `package1.package2` is explicitly imported.

Comment: That may be impossible (due to Class naming convention - its a java/python hybrid project) or take some serious large scale refactoring, is there a third option? I can live with the second option but no one-liner seems not flexible enough.